# php include file from different server

Tags: php, function, include

I'm trying to run a php function that's hosted on a different server. Here's the relevant code:

In firstdomain.com/handler.php:

```
include 'http://www.seconddomain.com/functions.php';
$disp_keyword = doQuery( 0, $keyword, null );
```

And in seconddomain.com/functions.php:

```
function doQuery( $code, $arg1, $arg2 ) {
    mail( 'myemail@aol.com', 'doquery entered', 'test' );
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You must be sure that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled and `allow_url_include` as well. Also make _absolutely_ sure that you know the contents of the file you are including remotely, and it is trusted 100%.

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 2):

Allot of servers default setup will stop this as its highly insecure but there is an easy work around using eval tho its just as insecure, if you dont 100% trust the source.

Instead of using

```
include 'http://www.seconddomain.com/functions.php';
```

use:

```
<?php 
//get file content, save it .txt on the serving server so its not interpreted,
// you could even encrypt it then base 64 it to keep it safe, then reverse the process
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.seconddomain.com/file.txt');
eval ("?>$content");
?>
```

or you could grab the file with FGC,save it and then just use a normal include, thou any method you choose you should be very wary of the source of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The file on the second server needs to output the PHP source, not just run it. When you include a remote file, it's like going there in your browser but then the code shown is run.

So, the easiest way to do this is to just leave out the `<?php` and `?>` tags. However bear in mind that this leaves your source code visible to the outside world - in particular any security is lost.